# getDeclaredMethod keeps giving NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I have seen some posts about the NoSuchMethodException with getDeclaredMethod but I still can't get rid of the problem.

I isolated the problem to a bare bones, can someone make this working:

```
public class MainMethodTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            //Method m = MainMethodTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("main");
            Method m = MainMethodTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("main", MainMethodTest.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to read up on the meaning of the second parameter of [`getDeclaredMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-). Hint: your `main` method doesn't have a parameter of type `MainMethodTest`.

Comment: ... neither does it have _no_ parameters (which applies to your commented line). Try it with `getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class)`.

Comment: Ah cool, I did try with `Sting.class` before but not with the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Method m = MainMethodTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("main", MainMethodTest.class);
```

Is trying to find `main(MainMethodTest argument)` method which you don't have in your code.

If you want to get `main(String[] argument)` method use

```
Method m = MainMethodTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter of the method `getDeclaredMethod` is the arguments of the method that you want to get. In your case, it is the main. So you have to specify the arg Parameters.

```
    Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class };
    Method main = MainMethodTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("main", argTypes);
```

Check this [code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/example/InvokeMain.java) on how to invoke the main method.